# Does Wallace Keefe know Lex Luthor's plan in Batman v. Superman?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

I was re-watching *Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice* the other day, and I was thinking...

Did Wallace Keefe (the former Wayne employee who was crippled when the building collapsed) know that Lex Luthor had embedded a bomb in his high-tech wheelchair? On first watch, I just figured Wallace knew but then I realized he doesn't really have a reason to know. Lex said he wanted Wallace to "stand for something" but wouldn't Wallace have assumed speaking in front of the Senator was the "stance" Lex wanted him to take? It also seemed like Lex's assistant didn't know the bomb was a plan either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

**This might only be from the Ultimate Edition, not the Theatrical Cut**

---

No, Wallace did not know that Lex embedded a bomb in his wheel chair.

If you remember from the movie, after the bomb in the wheel chair happened.. police and Lois went and inspected Wallace's home and Lois noticed that his refrigerator was full of fresh groceries and the fruit that was in the bowls was still fresh.

So, with observing that.. one could ask why would Wallace recently buy groceries if he knew he was going to die?  I believe Lois said in the movie that 'he didn't know he was going to die'.

Comment: That must be "Ultimate Edition" footage, right? I do not believe that was in the theatrical cut.

Comment: @DominicG. Good point, it might not be.  I can't remember from when I saw it in theatres, but I did purchase the ultimate edition.. so you might be right there.

Comment: No worries, it's an explanation regardless.  Thanks!

Comment: I remember both the cuts and this scene was not in theatrical cut.